# Difference in var and := in slice declaration go language

Tags: arrays, go

i have recently started working on go and was wondering with few of the ways to declare an slice

1. Without var -

> p := []int{}

2. With var

> var p = []int{}

Here are the two programs

First One

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    p := []int{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024}
    for i, v := range p {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
    }
}
```

Second One

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var p = []int{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024}
    for i, v := range p {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
    }
}
```

What's the primary difference in both the programs compilation, memory allocation and runtime ?

Comment: It's equivalent in your example

Answer (score 4):

> What's the primary difference in both the programs compilation, memory allocation and runtime ?

None.

(Note that there is also no secondary difference.)

The best advice for such questions is: Consult the language specification.

Comment: Yes, language spec is very small, compared to some _other_ languages. No excuse not to read it.